# Which files are inserted in Asset folder in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I am new programmer in UWP, I don't know when I insert my resources like images, audio, ... in Asset directory? beause I can insert my resources out of it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a convention. You can indeed still put your media files anywhere in your project.
But generally we tend to put them in the Asset folder.

Comment: you mean there is no difference? and I can put my logo and tiles out of Asset?